# How to calculate AMAT from SimpleScalar & Wattch simulator outputs?

Tags: caching, memory, optimization, simulation, cpu-architecture

I am using SimpleScalar & Wattch simulator to simulate cache. I want to find AMAT (Average Memory Access Time), formula is as follow:
`AMAT=hittimel1+missrtateL1*(hittimeL2+missrateL2*Misspenalty)`

Comment: Have you tried looking at the statistics printed? What exactly are you missing?

Comment: What Leeor said. A good strategy is to redirect output to a file and use a small awk/perl/python/ruby program to calculate the result and maybe generate an ouput graph.